# Error when coping a list into a Googlespreadsheet using gspread "TypeError: Object of type int64 is not JSON serializable"

Tags: python, gspread

When copying data from a Python DataFrame into a Googlespreadsheet, I encounter a TypeError when using sheet.insert_row on a list.

I have no problem using sheet.update_cell and add the values one by one, I was just wondering why insert_row is failing.
I'm using a Python notebook with Python version 3.7.1

```
df = pd.DataFrame([('a',1)],columns=columns)
sheet.insert_row(columns,1) # works
row = list(df.iloc[0])
print(row==['a',1]) # returns True
sheet.insert_row(['a',1], 2) # works
sheet.insert_row(row, 3) # Fails with error "TypeError: Object of type int64 is not JSON serializable"
```

I would expect the last two rows in the code to both succeed or fail, instead inserting ['a',1] works while ingesting row (even if row=['a',1]) fails with error "TypeError: Object of type int64 is not JSON serializable"